# Error: Class 'SplEnum' not found in PHP 7

Tags: php, enums, php-extension, pecl, spl

I have a project with PHP 7.3, under Windows 10. I use the PHP from [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html).

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SplEnum' not found in [...]

for

```
class BanLevel extends SplEnum { ... }
```

It seems I am misunderstanding the docu:

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php
2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.installation.php

This gives me the idea it should be included in my PHP artefact.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
The class.splenum.php page has gone offline. It is still available in Romanian, though:
 https://www.php.net/manual/ro/class.splenum.php, or here:
 https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/class.splenum

Comment: You must install and enable extensions in PHP.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I checked the wrong documentation,
this is the right one:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl-types.installation.php

It clarifies:

> This PECL extension is not bundled with PHP.
>
> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable.

So I can't use SPLEnum under Windows, except I compile it into PHP.

UPDATE:

The spl-types.installation.php page does not exist on php.net anymore, but it is still available here:
https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/spl-types.installation

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl-types.installation.php is dead but archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20201020032218/https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl-types.installation.php.  Is there a new live link?

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the info! I can't find any replacement for that documentation anywhere, just the Romanian version is still online: https://www.php.net/manual/ro/spl-types.installation.php

Comment: It seems, the [SPL Types package](https://pecl.php.net/package/spl_types) was replaced by the [SPL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/SPL)?